# sum of dependent bernoulli random variables is poisson?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose you have a sequence of bernoulli variables, $X_n$ with $\frac{1}{n} = \mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0)$ and let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k X_{k+1} $. The goal is that $S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$ is Poisson distributed with parameter 1. It's just dependent enough so that we can't apply the central limit theorem for triangular arrays. A friend and I were asked to prove this and we've been racking our heads against the wall with this.

Initially, I thought it might be false, but I computed the variance and some magical cancellation happens so that it gives you the right thing.

I have no idea how to proceed and most arguments I try end up becoming too complicated. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into the [Chen-Stein](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176991491) method? It may only give a bound on the TV distance between $S_n$ and a Poisson(1) RV, but it could be a start.

Comment: (I'm the friend of OP) Our adviser noted that the person who gave him the problem were experts on this stuff. We , unfortunately, don't know anything about it. We glanced it, and it does look mighty similar to the problem, but no answer yet. Thanks for the suggestion, we'll keep digging!